# Restrictions on exponential

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, exponentiation, radicals

This question has already been asked but no one answered so:

so i want to add restrictions to this list of exponent laws. The code i will post now is **my attempt at writing their restrictions and the laws i want to write restrictions on. SO, please let me know if my attempt is correct and if it's not i would like to see how to write them correctly.**

For all $\mathbf{b,c\in\mathbb{R}}$ and for all $\{a, d,d' \in \mathbb{R} | d,d'> 0\}$
$$d^b\cdot d^c=d^{b+c}$$
$$(d^b)^c=d^{bc}$$
$$(d \cdot d')^c=d^cd'^c$$
$$\left(\frac{d'}{d}\right)^b=\frac{d'^b}{d^b}$$
$$\frac{d^b}{d^c}=d^{b-c}$$
$$d^{-c}=\frac{1}{d^c}$$
$$a^{\frac{b}{d}}=\sqrt[d]{a^b}$$
$$\sqrt[d]{ab}=\sqrt[d]{a}\sqrt[d]{b},\quad\text{where} \textbf{ both } \text{a and b are non-negative}$$
$$\sqrt[d]{\frac{a}{b}}=\frac{\sqrt[d]{a}}{\sqrt[d]{b}},\quad\text{where} \textbf{ both } \text{a and b are non-negative}$$
$$\sqrt[d]{\sqrt[d']{a}}=\sqrt[dd']{a}$$

Comment: The question, in it's current form, lacks clarity. You should explain what you mean by "adding restrictions" and what you are really asking.

Comment: adding restrictions? like you know some of these laws aren't defined in some places, known as "restrictions". The laws are already there, and i added my attemp at writing the restrictions, i want to see if the restrictions are correct, or i've missed somewhere

Comment: Ah, I see. So you want to cross-check if it's correct, or if some assumptions are missing? What are d, d', integers?

Comment: whoops, no d,d' in R : d,d' =! 0

(Which is now edited in the question)

Comment: And yeah, i wanna see if there are any restrictions that are wrong and need anything else or if it's correct, let me know

Comment: Ok. Maybe saying it more clearly in the question would help, not to have the question deleted or downvoted, but I understand now what you mean.

Comment: So already the first line seems problematic: what is $d^b$ for negative $d$ and real $b$, like $(-1)^\pi$?

Comment: oh is that another form of undefined

Comment: that's true, so should how should i try to fix that?

Comment: I think you first need explicitely state with $b^b$ is defined and undefined first.  Then list these rules.  Example if $d < 0$ then $d^b$ is undefined for irrational $b$ and for $b$ rational with even denominator.  Also you jump from base $d$ to $a$ when you start doing roots and start assume $d$ is an natural number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is common to define powers $a^b$, $a,b$ real, for $a > 0$ and any $b$. If you consistently restrict all to this case only, I think that all of your rules will be satisfied without any problems.

If you want to allow $a \leq 0$, it's tricky. Sometimes you would like to have things such as $(-8)^{1/3}=-2$, but then if you start working with negative $a$'s, many or all of your other rules will fail; such as $((-4)^2)^{1/2}$ will be defined, but not equal to $(-4)^{2\times \frac{1}{2}}$ and $((-4)^{1/2})^2$ is not defined at all.

The power $a^b$ itself is often not well-defined for negative $a$, not even with complex numbers.

Comment: And $((-4)^2)^{1/2}$ doesn't equal $(-4)^{(2)(1/2)}$.

Comment: on the first line why do allow a=0, because for example 0^(-2) isn't defined either

Comment: Thank you both for the suggestions, edited.

Comment: so i should just add > 0 to all the bases? i think i use as bases the letters a, d and d'

Comment: Yes, and then you can also remove all of your "constraints", such as "if d is odd"

Comment: Of course, you could define $a^b$ for negative $a$ for some special cases where it makes sense... but then these rules would be just too complicated.